# Mock Bigquery function in kotlin unit test

Tags: kotlin, google-bigquery, mockk

I am develop an unit test, which involved (com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery). I mock the object with mockk @SpyK. But the every{} block report error when unit test start. Detail as follow

the dependency is:

```
"com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev20220326-1.32.1"
```

**The exception is throw in setUp() function**

**Code**

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class, SpringExtension::class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfidentialTags::class)
@PropertySource(value = ["classpath:application.yml"], factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory::class)
class ResourceAccessServiceTest {
    private val mockGoogleCredential = MockGoogleCredential.Builder().build()

    @SpyK
    private var olderBigQuery: Bigquery = Bigquery.Builder(
        MockGoogleCredential.newMockHttpTransportWithSampleTokenResponse(),
        mockGoogleCredential.jsonFactory,
        mockGoogleCredential
    ).build()

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var resourceAccessService: ResourceAccessService

 @BeforeAll
    fun setUp() {
        //error reported here
        every { olderBigQuery.RowAccessPolicies().list(any(), any(), any()).execute() } returns mockk() {
            every { rowAccessPolicies } returns listOf()
        }
    }



    @Test
    fun queryRowAccessExistedPrincipals() {
        val list = resourceAccessService.queryRowAccessExistedPrincipals(
            TableId.of("proj", "ds", "tbl"),
            RowFilter("region", listOf("hk"))
        )
        assert(list.isEmpty())
    }
}
```

**error log**

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: projects/2af774bb308513d5/datasets/-3e5359fe6b1a603f/tables/-28b905709f94ecc7/rowAccessPolicies
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: projects/2af774bb308513d5/datasets/-3e5359fe6b1a603f/tables/-28b905709f94ecc7/rowAccessPolicies
    at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.parseURL(GenericUrl.java:679)
    at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:125)
    at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:108)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequestUrl(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:373)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.airwallex.data.grpc.das.service.ResourceAccessServiceTest$setUp$1.invoke(ResourceAccessServiceTest.kt:67)
    at com.airwallex.data.grpc.das.service.ResourceAccessServiceTest$setUp$1.invoke(ResourceAccessServiceTest.kt:67)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$enhanceWithRethrow$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:78)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.JvmAutoHinter.autoHint(JvmAutoHinter.kt:23)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:40)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:93)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:98)
    at com.airwallex.data.grpc.das.service.ResourceAccessServiceTest.setUp(ResourceAccessServiceTest.kt:67)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:384)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
```

**The key error info is**

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: projects/2af774bb308513d5/datasets/-3e5359fe6b1a603f/tables/-28b905709f94ecc7/rowAccessPolicies
```

The exception is thrown in the every{} block in setUp function. It seems the url built inside the SDK is invalid, without protocol header. But I don't know how to solve the problems

Comment: Why do you want to mock BigQuery? If what you want to do is write a test for a component that talks to BigQuery, I don't see how it's valuable to mock it.

Comment: Because I can't create a real Bigquery instance connecting the GCP  in the unit test. That's not be permitted according company's engineer rules.

Comment: As I suspected. You often want to avoid calling external services in your tests because those tests can be brittle, slow, cost you(r company) money, etc.

Comment: Not exactly, the unit tests can't make impact on GCP, especially writing data.

Answer (score 0):

So what you really want is a way to decouple the code under test from BigQuery. The better way to do so that is to hide BigQuery behind your own abstraction (e.g. an interface) and make the code that needs to query only depend on that abstraction - look up the dependency inversion principle/dependency injection (I've got some answers here that show examples). That way, you can substitute a fake implementation in for testing that, say, queries against a collection in memory.

There is still one problem with this approach. You do at some point need to test against BigQuery for real. Otherwise, how will you prove that component works? I guess the possibilities here are constrained by what your company allows.

Comment: I think it is a little high-cost to develop a fake implementation just for a unit test. I just want to finish the test based on BigQuery api and MockK.  I have test against the 
real BigQuery in non-prod environment and it works well as expected.  Unit tests is  an essential process before deployed to production.